# Accuracy 99%, classification incorrect - triplet network

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a triplet network as described in the [facenet article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf).

I'm calculating the accuracy on the validation set by counting the triplets for which the positive distance (anchor - positive) is less than the negative distance (anchor - negative) and then dividing by the total number of triplets in the batch.

I get great results: 99% accuracy. But when I use my model embeddings to classify images (I take an unknown image and compare it - using Euclidean distance - with some labeled images) - only 20% results at most are correct.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Below you can find my detailed implementation.

---

**Triplet Generation**

**Before triplet generation, I've aligned and cropped both the training and the test set using dlib** (both CASIA and LFW) so the main elements of each face (eyes, noes, lips) are positioned nearly the same.

To generate the triplets, I randomly choose a CASIA folder with 40 or more images and then I choose 40 anchors, each of the anchors with a corresponding positive image (which is picked randomly but different from the anchor). Then I choose a random negative for each anchor-positive pair.

---

**Triplet loss**

Here's my triplet loss function:

```
def triplet_loss(d_pos, d_neg):

    print("d_pos "+str(d_pos))
    print("d_neg "+str(d_neg))

    margin = 0.2

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(0., margin + d_pos - d_neg))


    return loss
```

These are my **positive distance** (between anchor and positive) and **negative distance** (between anchor and negative).

```
**model1** = embeddings generated for the anchor image 
**model2** = embeddings generated for the positive image
**model3** = embeddings generated for the negative image
```

The variable **cost** is the loss I calculate at each step.

```
    d_pos_triplet = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(model1 - model2), 1)
    d_neg_triplet = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(model1 - model3), 1)

    d_pos_triplet_acc = tf.sqrt(d_pos_triplet + 1e-10)
    d_neg_triplet_acc = tf.sqrt(d_neg_triplet + 1e-10)

    d_pos_triplet_test = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(model1_test - model2_test), 1)
    d_neg_triplet_test = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(model1_test - model3_test), 1)

    d_pos_triplet_acc_test = tf.sqrt(d_pos_triplet_test + 1e-10)
    d_neg_triplet_acc_test = tf.sqrt(d_neg_triplet_test + 1e-10)


    cost = triplet_loss(d_pos_triplet, d_neg_triplet)
    cost_test = triplet_loss(d_pos_triplet_test, d_neg_triplet_test)
```

I then take the embeddings one by one **and test if the loss is positive** - because 0 loss means the network doesn't learn (as stated in the facenet article I have to choose **semi-hard** triplets)

```
input1,input2, input3, anchor_folder_helper, anchor_photo_helper, positive_photo_helper = training.next_batch_casia(s,e) #generate complet random

            s = i * batch_size
            e = (i+1) *batch_size

        input1,input2, input3, anchor_folder_helper, anchor_photo_helper, positive_photo_helper = training.next_batch_casia(s,e) #generate complet random


        lly = 0; 

        '''counter which helps me generate the same number of triplets each batch'''

        while lly < len(input1):

            input_lly1 = input1[lly:lly+1]
            input_lly2 = input2[lly:lly+1]
            input_lly3 = input3[lly:lly+1]

            loss_value = sess.run([cost], feed_dict={x_anchor:input_lly1, x_positive:input_lly2, x_negative:input_lly3})



            while(loss_value[0]<=0):
                ''' While the generated triplet has loss 0 (which means dpos - dneg + margin < 0) I keep generating triplets. I stop when I manage to generate a semi-hard triplet. '''
                input_lly1,input_lly2, input_lly3, anchor_folder_helper, anchor_photo_helper, positive_photo_helper = training.cauta_hard_negative(anchor_folder_helper, anchor_photo_helper, positive_photo_helper)
                loss_value = sess.run([cost], feed_dict={x_anchor:input_lly1, x_positive:input_lly2, x_negative:input_lly3})

                if (loss_value[0] > 0):
                    _, loss_value, distance1_acc, distance2_acc, m1_acc, m2_acc, m3_acc  = sess.run([accum_ops, cost, d_pos_triplet_acc, d_neg_triplet_acc, model1, model2, model3], feed_dict={x_anchor:input_lly1, x_positive:input_lly2, x_negative:input_lly3})
                 tr_acc = compute_accuracy(distance1_acc, distance2_acc)

                 if math.isnan(tr_acc) and epoch != 0:
                    print('tr_acc %0.2f' % tr_acc)
                    pdb.set_trace()
                    avg_loss += loss_value
                    avg_acc +=tr_acc*100

                    contor_i = contor_i + 1

                    lly = lly + 1
```

This is my model - note that when I apply L2 normalization my accuracy drops significantly (maybe I'm doing it wrong):

```
def siamese_convnet(x):

    w_conv1_1 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv1_1', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 1, 64])
    w_conv1_2 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv1_2', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 64, 64])

    w_conv2_1 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv2_1', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 64, 128])
    w_conv2_2 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv2_2', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 128, 128])

    w_conv3_1 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv3_1', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 128, 256])
    w_conv3_2 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv3_2', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 256, 256])
    w_conv3_3 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv3_3', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 256, 256])

    w_conv4_1 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv4_1', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 256, 512])
    w_conv4_2 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv4_2', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 512, 512])
    w_conv4_3 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv4_3', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[1, 1, 512, 512])

    w_conv5_1 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv5_1', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 512, 512])
    w_conv5_2 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv5_2', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[3, 3, 512, 512])
    w_conv5_3 = tf.get_variable(name='w_conv5_3', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[1, 1, 512, 512])

    w_fc_1 = tf.get_variable(name='w_fc_1', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[5*5*512, 2048])
    w_fc_2 = tf.get_variable(name='w_fc_2', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[2048, 1024])

    w_out = tf.get_variable(name='w_out', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), shape=[1024, 128])

    bias_conv1_1 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv1_1', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[64]))
    bias_conv1_2 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv1_2', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[64]))

    bias_conv2_1 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv2_1', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[128]))
    bias_conv2_2 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv2_2', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[128]))

    bias_conv3_1 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv3_1', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[256]))
    bias_conv3_2 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv3_2', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[256]))
    bias_conv3_3 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv3_3', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[256]))

    bias_conv4_1 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv4_1', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[512]))
    bias_conv4_2 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv4_2', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[512]))
    bias_conv4_3 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv4_3', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[512]))

    bias_conv5_1 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv5_1', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[512]))
    bias_conv5_2 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv5_2', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[512]))
    bias_conv5_3 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_conv5_3', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[512]))

    bias_fc_1 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_fc_1', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[2048]))
    bias_fc_2 = tf.get_variable(name='bias_fc_2', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[1024]))

    out = tf.get_variable(name='out', initializer=tf.constant(0.01, shape=[128]))

    x = tf.reshape(x , [-1, 160, 160, 1]);

    conv1_1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, w_conv1_1) + bias_conv1_1);
    conv1_2= tf.nn.relu(conv2d(conv1_1, w_conv1_2) + bias_conv1_2);

    max_pool1 = max_pool(conv1_2);

    conv2_1 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(max_pool1, w_conv2_1) + bias_conv2_1 );
    conv2_2 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(conv2_1, w_conv2_2) + bias_conv2_2 );

    max_pool2 = max_pool(conv2_2)

    conv3_1 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(max_pool2, w_conv3_1) + bias_conv3_1 );
    conv3_2 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(conv3_1, w_conv3_2) + bias_conv3_2 );
    conv3_3 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(conv3_2, w_conv3_3) + bias_conv3_3 );

    max_pool3 = max_pool(conv3_3)

    conv4_1 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(max_pool3, w_conv4_1) + bias_conv4_1 );
    conv4_2 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(conv4_1, w_conv4_2) + bias_conv4_2 );
    conv4_3 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(conv4_2, w_conv4_3) + bias_conv4_3 );

    max_pool4 = max_pool(conv4_3)

    conv5_1 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(max_pool4, w_conv5_1) + bias_conv5_1 );
    conv5_2 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(conv5_1, w_conv5_2) + bias_conv5_2 );
    conv5_3 = tf.nn.relu( conv2d(conv5_2, w_conv5_3) + bias_conv5_3 );

    max_pool5 = max_pool(conv5_3)

    fc_helper = tf.reshape(max_pool5, [-1, 5*5*512]);
    fc_1 = tf.nn.relu( tf.matmul(fc_helper, w_fc_1) + bias_fc_1 );

    fc_2 = tf.nn.relu( tf.matmul(fc_1, w_fc_2) + bias_fc_2 );

    output = tf.matmul(fc_2, w_out) + out
    #output = tf.nn.l2_normalize(output, 0) THIS IS COMMENTED


    return output
```

**My model in a framework independent manner:**

```
conv 3x3 (1, 64)
conv 3x3 (64,64)
max_pooling
conv 3x3 (64, 128)
conv 3x3 (128, 128)
max_pooling
conv 3x3 (128, 256)
conv 3x3 (256, 256)
conv 3x3 (256, 256)
max_pooling
conv 3x3 (256, 512)
conv 3x3 (512, 512)
conv 1x1 (512, 512)
max_pooling
conv 3x3 (256, 512)
conv 3x3 (512, 512)
conv 1x1 (512, 512)
max_pooling
fully_connected(128)
fully_connected(128)
output(128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your L2 normalization is feature-wise when it should be exemplar-wise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you please provide more details? What do you mean by exemplar-wise? Thank you!

Comment: @HelloLili did you figure out what exemplar wise means?

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji no, but I figured out what I was doing wrong: output = tf.nn.l2_normalize(output, 0) should be output = tf.nn.l2_normalize(output, axis=1)

Comment: @HelloLili I think this is what he meant. When you L2 normalize wrt to axis=0 (batch axis) you are normalizing it batch wise, when it is normalized along axis=1(embeddings of each training example(since u have a dense layer before l2 norm)) the normalization is exemplar wise. Makes sense?

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji yes, that's the explanation I was looking for! Thanks!